# GeoDjango: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'transform'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, geodjango

I have these three models below in which I want to achieved the following:

- Get all the geom(ButuanMaps) owned by the specific owner(Owner)
- Display the geom(ButuanMaps) information from the LandProperty model

models.py

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('Male', 'Male'),
        ('Female', 'Female'),
    )
    MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('Single', 'Single'),
        ('Married', 'Married'),
        ('Widowed', 'Widowed'),
        ('Divorced', 'Divorced'),
    )
    user= models.OneToOneField(User)
    spersonid = models.ForeignKey(Information)
    ctin = models.CharField("TIN",max_length=50)
    csss = models.CharField("SSS", max_length=50)
    crescertificate = models.CharField("Res. Certificate", max_length=50)
    cgender = models.CharField("Gender", max_length=10, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    cmaritalstatus = models.CharField("Marital Status", max_length=50, choices=MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)

    User.profile = property(lambda u: Owner.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.spersonid.cfirstname


class ButuanMaps(gismodel.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Butuan Map'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Butuan Maps'

    clandpin = gismodel.CharField("Land PIN", max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    ssectionid = gismodel.ForeignKey(Section)
    #ssectionid_id = gismodel.IntegerField()
    geom = gismodel.MultiPolygonField("Geom ID", srid=32651, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = gismodel.GeoManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.clandpin


class LandProperty(models.Model):
    DEFAULT_OWNER_ID = 5
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Land Property'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Land Properties'
    ctaxdec = models.CharField("Tax Declaration", max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    sgeomid = models.ForeignKey(ButuanMaps)
    sownerid = models.ForeignKey(Owner, default=DEFAULT_OWNER_ID)
    clotno = models.CharField("Lot Nos.", max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    iblockno = models.IntegerField("Block Nos.", null=True, blank=True)
    csurveyno = models.CharField("Survey Nos.", max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    cstreet = models.CharField("Street", max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    nfrontage = models.CharField("Frontage", max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    nkmstoweather = models.FloatField("Kms. to Weather", null=True, blank=True)
    nkmstomarket = models.FloatField("Kms. to Market", null=True, blank=True)
    cnorth = models.CharField("North", max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    csouth = models.CharField("South", max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    ceast = models.CharField("East", max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    cwest = models.CharField("West", max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.sgeomid.clandpin
```

views.py

```
def display_agao(request, ):
    search_term = request.GET.get("q", None)
    #query_agao = ButuanMaps.objects.filter(clandpin=search_term)
    x = Owner.objects.select_related('landproperty_butuanmaps').get(id=5)
    query_agao = x.landproperty_set.all()
    query_all = ButuanMaps.objects.all()
    djf = Django.Django(geodjango='geom', properties=['id', 'clandpin'])
    geoj = GeoJSON.GeoJSON()
    butuan_agao = geoj.encode(djf.decode(query_agao.transform(3857)))
    return render(request, "index.html", {
        'butuan_agao': butuan_agao,
        'query_agao': query_agao,
        'query_all': query_all})
```

Comment: In `query_agao.transform()` `query_agao` is a queryset and the dot notation is used only for referencing keys of objects. hence the issue

Comment: Ok! So, how to I render the shape file based on a query?